# Notation for the position and momentum differentials in a system of $N$ particles and $d$ dimensions

Tags: statistical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, notation, phase-space

I am a little confused with the notation used in Statistical Mechanics for the differentials of position and momentum in the phase space. For instance, I have found different notations in different sources for the expression of the volume $ \Gamma_{N}(E,V)$ in the phase space of a system of $N$ identical particles and $d$ dimensions (with $f=Nd$ degrees of freedom):

$$ \Gamma_{N}(E,V)=\frac{1}{h^{f} N !} \int_{E_{0} \leq \mathcal{H}\{p, q\} \leq E}  d^{f} \vec{q} d^{f} \vec{p} \\ =\frac{1}{h^{f} N !} \int_{E_{0} \leq \mathcal{H}\{p, q\} \leq E} \prod_{i=1}^{N} d^{d} \vec{q}_{i} d^{d} \vec{p}_{i} \\ =\frac{1}{h^{f} N !} \int_{E_0\leq\mathcal{H}\{p, q\}\leq E} dq dp  \\ = \frac{1}{h^{f} N !}\int_{E_0\leq\mathcal{H}\{p, q\}\leq E} \{d p, d q\}$$

Would all of them simply be reduced to the following expression?

$$d^fq\space d^fp=(dq_{1,1}dq_{1,2}...dq_{1,d})(dq_{2,1}dq_{2,2}...dq_{2,d})...(dq_{N,1}dq_{N,2}...dq_{N,d})\\
·(dp_{1,1}dp_{1,2}...dp_{1,d})(dp_{2,1}dp_{2,2}...dp_{2,d})...(dp_{N,1}dp_{N,2}...dp_{N,d})$$

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make a generalization about the notation used in all textbooks, but in the context of Statistical Mechanics it is usually understood that $d^fq \space d^fp=d^f\mathbf q \space d^f\mathbf p=d^f\vec q \space d^f\vec p$, where $d\vec a$ stands for (for example, in 3 dimensions) $d\vec a=da_xda_yda_z$ instead of $d\vec a=da_x\hat i +da_y \hat j + da_z\hat i$. Then, if $f=Nd$,

$$d^fq \space d^fp=d^f\mathbf q \space d^f\mathbf p=d^f\vec q \space d^f\vec p= \displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{N} {d^dq_i \space d^dp_i}=\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{N}\displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^{d} {dq_{ij} \space dp_{ij}}$$

Which is indeed what you wrote.